# Is there an online version of fancytree javascript hosted on googlecode that can be directly included in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancytree

In order to include jQuery and jQueryUI libraries we can use below code in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to use something similar to include Fancy Tree plugin using a url and not downloading the file from http://plugins.jquery.com/fancytree/

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There is **no** CDN for Fancytree.</strike>

Note that linking to another site (except for official CDNs such as googleapis) to include ressources will steal bandwidth from that server, so its considered *unfair*.

**Update:** as of 09-2014 there is a CDN version available:

- http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jquery.fancytree
- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.fancytree